# Mapbox Callout Image

Tags: image, firebase, mapbox, callout

I have a question about Mapbox Callouts. I was wondering if it was possible to turn the standard white callout background into an image. I want my annotation callout to have this image and when clicked segue to a view controller displaying a large image of the location. I would normally use a right or left calloutAccessoryView button, however, I am already using these two buttons for different functions. Does anybody know if this is possible? I have done a fair bit of research and it seems that there are no definite ways of creating this (although it seems extremely simple in MapKit!!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, it's built into the Mapbox API. You use the MGLMapViewDelegate method `optional func mapView(_ mapView: Any!, tapOnCalloutForAnnotation annotation: Any!)` From the website:

> This method is called when the user taps on the body of the callout view, as opposed to the callout’s left or right accessory view. If the annotation has a custom callout view via the -mapView:calloutViewForAnnotation: method, this method is only called whenever the callout view calls its delegate’s -[MGLCalloutViewDelegate calloutViewTapped:] method.
>
> If this method is present on the delegate, the standard callout view’s
>   body momentarily highlights when the user taps it, whether or not this
>   method does anything in response to the tap.

[Example usage](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/custom-callout/)